# How to get the main Activity in a fragment extedend from SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I have:
**MainActivity**

```
fragment = new ListReportsFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

With this simple code I am calling a framgment extended from `SupportMapFragment`

**MyFragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getParentFragment().getActivity()
    }
}
```

But the value of `main` is always `null` . How I can send or get the `MainActivity` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getParentFragment().getActivity();
```

with

```
MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```